# Can we trigger a mono-stable multi-vibrator( using 555 IC ) using mono audio signal?

Tags: signal, trigger, multivibrator, monostable

I'm working on a project where, a certain low frequency audio spike should trigger the mono-stable multi-vibrator. If we can trigger a mono-stable multi-vibrator using a mono audio signal, how much is the amplitude needed to trigger this multi-vibrator?

Comment: It depends on the chip technology and (usually) power supply voltages.

Comment: The multivibrator's datasheet will answer that.

Comment: Sorry I'm edited. The circuit consisting of 555 Timer IC and how can I define the trigger input amplitude for it?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot from an oscilloscope of the audio spike?  Any description of it?  Do you need an audio low-pass filter?  If it's just a vague "Can I use a signal to trigger a multi-vibrator?" then the vague answer is "Yes."  If you provide specific information about voltages, frequencies, etc then you can get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on everything surrounding the monostable.  What voltages are available for the circuit?  What circuit or system does the output drive.  These help determine the actual monostable circuit.  For example, if it is a 12 V circuit made up of CMOS Schmitt trigger logic gates, then the input trigger levels are around 5 V and 7 V above GND.  You could bias the audio signal up to around 8 V DC with a coupling capacitor, and a negative 4 V peak would trigger the monostable.  OR, with opamps or comparators running on anything from 5 V ro 24 V, the audio could be centered about GND and trigger a comparator with a positive 0.5 V peak.

1. What voltage or voltages are available for the monostable circuit?
2. What voltage or voltages are available for an audio amplifier (if needed)?
3. What does the monostable output drive?

Answer (score 0):

By default, 555 trigger and threshold happen at 1/3 Vcc and 2/3 Vcc.

There is, however, a control voltage input, Vc, which will cause trigger and threshold to happen at 1/2Vc and Vc.  That input is often used for modulation applications.  There may be limits on what are legal values for Vc.  Check a data sheet.

Comment: Can Vc be used to reduce the audio voltage required to trigger the monostable? If so then how does it do it, and what is the smallest voltage it could work with?

Comment: @BruceAbbott -- the setpoints to the internal comparators on a 555 are simple set by three equal resistors tied to Vcc.  The Vc input simply bypasses the first resistor, and ties directly to the set point of the Threshold comparator.  The TI lm555 version specifies a control voltage level of 2.4 to 4 volts when Vcc=5V.  I suspect this only has to do with the power rating of the internal resistors, and that there may be 555's with beefier resistors.

Comment: I've used the modulation circuits of figures 8 and 10 of datasheet.octopart.com/LM555CM/NOPB-National-Semiconductor-datasheet-7283993.pdf with considerably lower voltages, but it probably isn't the best idea.  Adding a DC to the line voltage is probably the way to go.